# Fundamentals of SQL (subquery topic)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to come up with a solution to the following query:

Display an `(*)` in front of **recently hired employee and hire date**. Make sure you display all the other employees as well.

I am trying to solve the above query **WITHOUT USING UNION**. I came close with the solution but it **prints stars (*) in front of all the rows**. Here is my solution:

```
SELECT ENAME, HIREDATE, LPAD('*',2)
FROM EMP
WHERE HIREDATE = (SELECT MAX(HIREDATE)
                  FROM EMP)
OR HIREDATE != (SELECT MAX(HIREDATE)
                FROM EMP);
```

I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong when I am using `LPAD('*', 2)` just cant seem to figure out what I am missing.

Comment: What platform are you using, how do you define recent?

Comment: Sorry for late reply Hogan. My Internet wasn't working. Platform I am using is sqlplus. and according to EMP table in SCOTT schema the most recently hired employee is ADAMS and his hiredate is 23-MAY-87.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would display a star in front of the most recent 10%

```
SELECT CASE WHEN hireorder <= cnt/10 THEN '*' ELSE '' END AS star,
       ename,
       hiredate 
FROM (
  SELECT ename, hiredate, 
         ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ename ORDER BY hiredate DESC) as hireorder,
         COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
  FROM EMP
) sub
```

This will work on DB2, Oracle and SQL Server.  Other platforms too.  You didn't say what you were using.

Comment: Thanks. Although that wasn't exactly the solution I was looking since I am yet to reach ROWNUMBER(), OVER(), PARTITION BY functions and keywords; it gave me a perfect idea for the exact solution using case with the same output. Here's the solution I came up with:         SELECT CASE WHEN HIREDATE = (SELECT MAX(HIREDATE) FROM EMP) THEN '*' ELSE ' '  END AS STAR, ENAME, HIREDATE FROM EMP;